# How to search / print specific ((files, folders or files with extension))

Tags: python, list, os.walk

```
import os 

for r,d,f in os.walk("c:\"): 
    for files in f: 
        if files == "abc.txt": 
            print os.path.join(r,files)
```

I saw someone post the code up top and it worked very well for me, is there a way to create a list of words and append it to the " for " loop so that the loop goes through all the words to try and find matching results? and once one of the words in the list has been found, what is the proper syntax to print the full location path of the file found

Thanks

Comment: `os.path.join(r, files)` should gives you full location.

Comment: this code is for `Python 2` because it uses `print` without `()`. In `Python 3` you have to use `print(....)`

Comment: HI , Thank you for the comment. you're right it's my mistake i should've corrected the print().

Comment: you can't add words to current `for`-loops - you have to create another `for`-loop for this - `for word in list_of_words: if files == word: ...`

Comment: it would be more readable if you would use better names for variables - `for root, dirs, files in os.walk(...)` and later `for filename in files: ... ` and `if filename == "abc.txt": ...`

Comment: thank you for the tip , i am currently in python practicing coding and i will change the syntax to make it more readable . cheers much appreciated . and thank you kindly for the for word in list_of_words : if files == word... <- I will work on that asap. =-)  cheers

Comment: @ack Oh, yes - I would have to thinking about partial words

Answer (score 0):

You can't add list to existing `for`-loop - you have to add another `for`-loop

```
import os

list_of_words = ['abc.txt', 'script.py']

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("c:"):
    for filename in files:
        for word in list_of_words:
            if word == filename:
                print( os.path.join(root, filename) )
```

And if you want to see partial words then you may need `in` instead of `==`

```
            if word in filename:
```

If filename may have upper case or lower case name then you can also use `.lower()` or `.upper()` to compare it

```
            if word.lower() in filename.lower():
```

And if you want check word at the end of `filename` (ie. to check only extensions)

```
            if filename.lower().endswith( word.lower() ):
```

`endswith()` may get even `list` or `tuple`

```
            if filename.lower().endswith( [".jpg", ".png", ".gif"] ):
```

Similar method `.startswith()`

```
            if filename.lower().startswith( ["image_", "dimg_"] ):
```

Comment: you truly are awesome, thank you very much for the detailed coding. i am literally rearranging the coding in python as i saw your post. Again Thank you x a million

Comment: @KhalilG there is also `glob.glob()` which can use `*` instead some parts of name.

Comment: glob.glob()  would be a little outside my skills league haha , i'm still somewhat new to python as i would rather be good with the fundamentals prior to learning new packages etc... =-)